# Print data in console in python

Tags: python, string, typeerror

I am looking to print some data on screen in python, I use the formatting of strings so that they are presented in an orderly and rounded way, this data is printed based on a conditional.

I have created two variables: If a > b, rounded numbers should be printed like this:

```
01         -807.8
02        -6337.8
03        -6045.9
04       -15531.6
05       -26803.0
06       -40534.2
07        20364.4
08        12678.4
```

But if a < b, a text like this should be printed:

```
01       Does not apply
02       Does not apply
03       Does not apply
04       Does not apply
05       Does not apply
06       Does not apply
07       Does not apply
08       Does not apply
09       Does not apply
10       Does not apply
```

The problem is that:
When executing the command if a> b the values are printed, but if a < b, I get an error: *TypeError: type str doesn't define __round_ method.*

Is there a way to correct that problem?

My code is as follows:

```
datos = [[1,1154,5412],[2,4527,5698],[3,2879,-5687],[4,5547,-5698],[5,7658,6589],
     [6,9651,-4565],[7,-4156,-6548],[8,-2264,6568],[9,-1657,6597],[10,-1643,5481]]

for i in range(len(datos)):

    a = 7
    b = 8

    if a < b:                
        Respuesta = 'Does not apply'                  
    elif a > b:            
        Respuesta = (0.7*datos[i][0]*datos[i][1])/(b-a)    

    print(f"{i+1:02} {round(Respuesta, 2):>20}")
```

Comment: What would `round('Does not apply', 2)` mean?

Comment: Round the value in the `elif` suite ... `Respuesta = {round(Respuesta, 2)` then it won't be in the print function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways, but this is probably the simplest:

```
    if a < b:                
        Respuesta = 'Does not apply'                  
    elif a > b:            
        Respuesta = round((0.7*datos[i][0]*datos[i][1])/(b-a), 2)

    print(f"{i+1:02} {Respuesta:>20}")
```

Answer (score 0):

if `a < b` your variable `Respuesta` will be this string `'Does not apply'` which will be used with the [round](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function that will raise your error because the `round` built-in function accepts only numbers as argument

you can use:

```
for i in range(len(datos)):

    a = 7
    b = 8

    if a < b:                
        print('Does not apply')
    elif a > b:            
        Respuesta = (0.7*datos[i][0]*datos[i][1])/(b-a)    

        print(f"{i+1:02} {round(Respuesta, 2):>20}")
```

---

since  in your code, `a` is always < `b` (7<8) you can use the following one line:

```
print(*['Does not apply'] * len(datos), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback.